# Let $G$ be a group of order 100 with exactly one subgroup of order 5. Prove that it has a subgroup of order 10.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $100$ that has exactly one subgroup of order $5.$ Prove that it has a subgroup of order $10.$

I think some property of cosets is needed. But I am not very comfortable with using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be the subgroup of order $5$. Clearly, $N\lhd G$. The quotient $G/N$ has order $20$, hence some element $hN$ of order $2$. Then the preimageof $\langle hN\rangle$ has order $10$.